# Android ImageView Image too big

Tags: android, image, size, android-imageview

this is my Situation:

- `FrameLayout` `with`/`height` 160dp (The View of a Toast)
- `ImageView` in the `FrameLayout` that should show an image on 140dp

So i thought the `FrameLayout` with 160dp is 1 inch (2,54 cm). Correct?
My image in Illustrator is 0.87 inch (2,2 cm) and i exported it with 320 ppi. The final pixel size is 277px.

The problem is that my mobile shows the image with round about 1 inch (2,54 cm).  And that is to big! The density of my Sony Xperia Z3 are round about 430 ppi.

[image: The white box is 160dp (1 inch), the arrow image 277px (0.87 inch)]
[image: This one shows how it should look like]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:id="@+id/too_much_items_toast_root"
    android:background="@drawable/toast_background_white">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bamaki_zoom_in"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Zoomen"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Where i´m wrong? Or what do i have to do that the image fits in the Layout with some space to the edges?

Comment: Do you want to match your image to Locate Me Icon?

Comment: look, the right one is what i like. But the right image is only 225px. How do i have to calculate how big (pixel) my image have to be to fit in this 160dp box with some margin?

Comment: You have to post your Layout file as well to show how you are layout this layout.

Comment: so that is the layout

Comment: You could set FrameLayout width/height to wrap_content and give padding 20dp.This way you will have Frame like on the right side.

Comment: Okay that is great. But now the FrameLayout is not 160dp but 160dp + 20dp padding. The Image is exactly the same size...
What is the correct way to calculate the image size? Or is there no "correct" image size for me?

Comment: I ended up having to use `wrap_content` + `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `FrameLayout` width/height to `wrap_content` and give padding `20dp`.This way you will have Frame like on the right side.

Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/too_much_items_toast_root"
    android:background="@drawable/toast_background_white">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bamaki_zoom_in"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Zoomen"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Updated: Correct way to calculate image size
[image]

Forget DPI for a second. Before you start making image size first come up with a base size. That size would go to MDPI folder of drawable. Then make 1.5 times that size for HDPI folder, 2 times that size for XHDPI folder, 3 times the size for XXHDPI folder.

Comment: okay and what is the correct base size for my case? How big would you make this image?
By the way, thanks for the answer, but maybe you could answer me this last thing

Comment: It is up to you, how big you want this image to be? Do you want it to be a big image in the middle or match Locate Me image?

Comment: I´d like it to be the size of 140dp. Or is it not possible to make an image that is exactly 140dp?

Comment: Use this calculator to find out how much is 140dp in pixels for different android densities and make those sizes in pixel and put in their drawable folders. http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/